Born oppenheimer approximation error
I got this exam question including BOA:
'rank the molecules according to increasing error value of the Born-Oppenheimer Approximation: H2, Cl2, F2, KCl, PtCl4, CH4'.
my rank is:
H2, CH4, F2, Cl2, KCl, PtCl4.
My tutor said that the BOA is fulfilled best for molecules with heavier nuclei cause of kinetic energy term that is inversivly proportional to mass, but i thought that if we have heavier atoms, the BOA is breaking cause of non-adiabatic coupling.
What are your thought on this?

The answer would depend on what property you want to calculate, for example total energy or bond length. A heavy atom molecule with a very flat potential energy surface may be less sensitive to the BOA than a light atom molecule with a stiff potential energy surface in terms of the total energy, but not in terms of the average bond length.

so id assume the question is about the electron energy error arising from BOA
